# Measure the length of the lowercase alphabet

Tags: memoir, lengths

The memoir manual mentions

> measuring the length of the lowercase alphabet

in order to decide the numbers of characters per line. Can this be done with LaTeX?

Comment: Both answers seem to be equal correct and elegant (at least to my eyes). I can't decide which one I should accept...

Comment: My answer is the "official" LaTeX way, while Yiannis one uses plainTeX macros. I personally actually use that macros more often because you only need to box the content once and get the height, width and depth using `\ht`, `\wd` and `\dp` respectively.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If with the *length* it means the width of all lowercase letters than you can use `\settowidth{<length register>}{<content>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newlength{\alphabetlength}
  \settowidth{\alphabetlength}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
  \the\alphabetlength
\end{document}
```

(I took the liberty to use the same format as Yiannis answer to allow for better comparison. His answer is fine too, but I wanted to show the official LaTeX way.)

Answer (score 17):

You can place the letters in a box and measure its length. Here is a minimal to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newbox\alphabet
  \sbox\alphabet{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
  \the\wd\alphabet
\end{document}
```

Comment: @pmav99 \textgreek{parakal`w}

Comment: @Yiannis You are hardcore! This is the Unicode age :P

Comment: I finally chose Martin's answer as he uses one less `\\` ... LOL

Comment: @pmav99 I see, my solution was optimized for the minimum number of curly brackets!

Comment: @Yiannis: then replace `\sbox\alphabet{...}` by `\savebox\alphabet\hbox\bgroup...\egroup`.

Answer (score 8):

Just for the record, page 15 of `memman.pdf` brings the following to print the length of the lowercase alphabet:

```
\newlength{\mylen}                % a length
\newcommand{\alphabet}{abc...xyz} % the lowercase alphabet
\begingroup                       % keep font change local
% font specification e.g., \Large\sffamily
\settowidth{\mylen}{\alphabet}
The length of this alphabet is \the\mylen. % print in document
\typeout{The length of the Large sans alphabet
    is \the\mylen}                         % put in log file
\endgroup                         % end the grouping
```

Which is basically @Martin's way.