# Nicely force 66 characters per line

Tags: macros, packages, margins, memoir, koma-script

I would like to have "something" (a package, a trick, a macro, ...?) that makes it possible for me to nicely play with the margins (or the layout) in order to set the average or typical number of characters per line.

Ideally, this "system" would help me keep this ratio (66, 2.5 alphabets, or any other number I choose/input) independent from changes in font families (such as with the use of the package `pslatex` or `txfonts` for example), in font sizes (with a `10pt` or `12pt` class option for example).

I've looked around a bit, and I kind of understood, that using KOMA-Script classes or the `memoir` class may be part of a solution, be I would prefer not (especially because I have never used any so far).

An important point for me is that the whole proportions or principles of the original layout must be kept. For example, if there was a set ratio between left and right margins, then, just playing around with one margin or with textwidth/linewidth would not satisfy me.

Why I'd like to do this? Because I like to use the `pslatex` package, but this put the average number of charaters per line from about 65 without to about 75+ with.

Note, I have already gone or skimmed through:

- [Best ratios of number of letters per line and of number of lines per page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/best-ratios-of-number-of-letters-per-line-and-of-number-of-lines-per-page)
- [Are there any good general typesetting books / references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13874/are-there-any-good-general-typesetting-books-references)
- http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf

And, also there may be answers there, I couldn't (too easily) find them.

Comment: The necessary part of KOMA-script can be used standalone:\usepackage[DIV=calc]{typearea} . Maybe this helps.

Comment: @S. Schubert: This is a very interesting idea. I just tried it. It could do the trick. However, it tends to put the bottom of the page (end of text, page numbers...) a bit too high for my taste.

Comment: @S. Schubert: Another problem (that I think I've seen) is that it seems to work better (or only?) with the `a4paper` option for the `article` class
[and less (or not?) with the `letterpaper` option]. If this is true, I'd be curious to know why...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The statement about 2.5 times the length of the lowercase alphabet is just an indication. However you can play with `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{book}

%%\usepackage{newtxtext}
\newlength{\alphabet}
\settowidth{\alphabet}{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=2.5\alphabet,hmarginratio={2:3}}

\begin{document}
\the\textwidth
\end{document}
```

This will use a ratio for the margins as indicated (2:3 is actually the default, in twoside mode). Well behaved font packages should work correctly.

With the default fonts I get a textwidth of 318.96pt, while with `newtxtext` I get 298.58pt (with `mathptmx` the result is 298.57pt).

Notice that `pslatex` is a very obsolete package and that its descendant `mathptmx` is rather inadequate for serious typesetting involving math. If you don't need mathematics, other choices based on (Linotype) Times Roman are

- `newtxtext` (based on `txfonts`, but with corrected metrics)
- `tgtermes`

The former has the companion math package `newtxmath`.

You can choose whatever ratio you prefer for the margins. It's customary, in twoside printing, to have the outer margin wider than the inner one. If you want to automatize the choice between oneside printing (equal margins) and twoside, then

```
\geometry{textwidth=2.5\alphabet}
\makeatletter
\if@twoside
  \geometry{hmarginratio={2:3}}
\else
  \geometry{hmarginratio={1:1}}
\fi
\makeatother
```

could be used. The options for `geometry` can be given in distinct `\geometry` commands. Don't forget to specify the paper size (you can do it either in `\geometry` or as a class option).

You can also test the loaded class:

```
\makeatletter
\geometry{hmarginratio={1:1}} % fallback

\@ifclassloaded{book}
 {
  \if@twoside
    \geometry{hmarginratio={2:3}}
  \else
    \geometry{hmarginratio={1:1}}
  \fi
 }{}

\@ifclassloaded{article}
 {
  \if@twoside
    \geometry{hmarginratio={4:2}}
  \else
    \geometry{hmarginratio={1:1}}
  \fi
 }{}
\makeatletter
```

(the setting 4:2 is just by way of example).

However there's no "catch all" format: what you finally choose for a document depends on the document itself.

---

How to set the horizontal margin ratio to be equal to that fixed by the class? This is a bit difficult, because the standard setting uses a different model than `geometry`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newlength{\alphabet}
\sbox0{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\setlength{\alphabet}{\wd0}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\dimendef\innermargin=\z@
\dimendef\outermargin=\tw@
\innermargin=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\hoffset\relax
\outermargin=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\innermargin-\textwidth\relax
\outermargin=.002\outermargin
\innermargin=2\innermargin
\count@=\innermargin
\divide\count@ \outermargin
\xdef\standardhmarginratio{\number\count@:1000}
\endgroup

\geometry{textwidth=2.5\alphabet,hmarginratio=\standardhmarginratio}

\begin{document}

text width = \the\textwidth

horizontal margin ratio = \standardhmarginratio

\end{document}
```

With the `article` class we get 1000:1000, with `book` (twoside mode) the result is 667:1000 that's, for all practical purposes, 2:3.

Comment: Your alphabet doesn't have x. Why not just use 26em?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the extra comments on `pslatex`. However, I suspect that `hmarginratio={2:3}` would be specific to the `book` class and would need to be changed for another class (such as `article` or `letter`). If I'm right, then I can't accept your answer (yet).

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Thanks for spotting the missing letter. The `em` is usually the width of an uppercase M, so 26em is way larger than `\alphabet`.

Comment: @egreg: do you know if `hmarginratio` can be obtained? I mean, could you do something like: define `ThisClassRatio` by getting the numbers from commands and then `\geometry{textwidth=2.5\alphabet,hmarginratio={ThisClassRatio}}`.

Comment: @Christophe The standard classes use a different model for defining the page parameters. I'll add some example of computation.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks again for putting so much effort in your answer(s). Quick extra (actually late) question: Doesn't the `geometry` package by default keep the `hmarginratio` as it would be without it? In this case, wouldn't computing `\standardhmarginratio` and entering the <key>=<value> pair (`hmarginratio=\standardhmarginratio`) redundant or an over-kill?

Comment: @Christophe `geometry` uses `2:3` as default for twoside and `1:1` for oneside, independently of what the class thinks about the margins.

Comment: Quick remark following [Measure the length of the lowercase alphabet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17399/measure-the-length-of-the-lowercase-alphabet). Instead of using 
`\newlength{\alphabet}` + `\sbox0{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}` + `\setlength{\alphabet}{\wd0}` ; one can use `\newlength{\alphabet}` + `\settowidth{\alphabet}{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}`.

Comment: @egreg --- an em is _not_ the width of a `M`, it's a horizontal measure equal to the size of the type, so an em for a 12 point font is 12 points.

Comment: @WillAdams The *em* is, traditionally, the horizontal size of an uppercase "M". But nowadays it's a horizontal length somewhat related to the size of a font, but no law prescribes it's the same as the point size. Indeed it isn't for many TeX fonts (try `cmbx10`, for instance).

Answer (score 30):

Robert Bringhurst,  in ["The Elements of Typographic Style"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063), gives a table of preferred line lengths for different fonts. A least squares optimization fit of the table data revealed that it can be approximated quite well with the following macro:

```
\newcommand*\GetTextWidth[3][\normalfont]{{#1%
    \settowidth{#2}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}%
    \setlength{#2}{0.03193#2}%
    \addtolength{#2}{0.44961pt}%
    \setlength{#2}{#3#2}%
    \global#2=#2}}
```

Which can be used together with `geometry`, etc. to set the text width

```
\newlength\bringhurstwdt
\GetTextWidth{\bringhurstwdt}{66}
\geometry{textwidth=\bringhurstwdt}
```

I assume that this is valid for standard English which have relative short words. In a language such as Afrikaans (my native language) we have a lot very long words and the 66 characters per line does not alway look right. For other languages the character count for good typography may differ, but I have no idea what would be best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm a bit lost in the units and variables used. 
Maybe you could help me on this: 
Do you know if the formula you're using (from ["The Elements of Typographic Style"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063)) is related in anyway to the one given in the `memoir` class documentation ([here](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)) (section 2.4, page 13)? 
Thanks again.

Comment: @Christophe: My formula is basicaly L = (0.03193 W + 0.44961pt)*N with W the alphabet width in points, N the number of chars and L the line width in points. The formula in `memoir` is for N=65 and it differs slightly from mine but not by much.

Comment: Very useful. It seems that one has to add `\normalsize` after `\normalfont` in order to get results suitable for 11pt or 12pt documents.

Answer (score 20):

ConTeXt provides a macro called `\averagecharwidth` that calculates the average width of a character based on language specific character frequency. There is no proper interface for it, so you have manually load the required files.

```
 \input lang-frq.mkii %macros to calculate average length
 \input lang-frd.mkii %language frequency tables

 \setuplayout[width=66\averagecharwidth]
```

See [lang-frd.mkii](http://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/lang-frd.mkii) for language frequency tables, and [lang-frq.mkii](http://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/lang-frq.mkii) for macros to calculate average width.
From the documentation:

> This module implements a method for determining the width of an
>   average character in a language. It uses the dimensions of the
>   current fonts.
>
> Method~1 ignores the widths and assumes that each character has a
>   width of .5em, which is true for most monospaced fonts. Method~2
>   takes the x as starting point, and assumes that it's height kind of
>   matches its width. Method~3 is the best one, and determines the
>   average width based on the language specific character table.
>   Method~4 is a mixture between the first two methods: character
>   specific widths applied to an equal distribution. Method~0 reports
>   the total count, which normally is~100.

The documentation also includes the following figure showing the frequency tables for English, Dutch, and German.

[image]

Although the files have `.mkii` extension, the code is fairly low-level TeX and works with ConTeXt MkIV as well. It should also work with LaTeX with minor changes.

For a true "average of 66 characters per line", you can first preprocess your text to generate the frequency table, and then use that frequency table to compute the average character width!

**Note**: The `\averagecharwidth` macro takes the font sizes from the current font and chooses the character frequency from the current language. So, it should be used after the document font and language have been specified.

Comment: I am more and more fascinated by ConTeXt.

Comment: @Aditya there is a similar method in latex?

Comment: @Sveinung: come to the dark side, we have cookies! (Easter eggs?)