# A5-paper document with 55 letter on one line

Tags: document-configuration

Is it possible to write a document for A5-paper such that I can configure its margin widths and letter spacing such that a line contains at most roughly 55 letters?

Comment: Are you using a monospace font?  If not, you might run into trouble that an "m" is wider than an "i"...

Comment: Not necessary. The problem is that I was writing a book for my customer and she wants me to write the book with paper size given in another book. So that 55 is an approximate number of letters one line contains.

Comment: Related: [Nicely force 66 characters per line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59626/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package to set your margins how you like, and add Koma-script functionality with `scrextend` to set the base font size with `\changefontsizes`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

It looks like that first line has 53-55 characters in it...

[image: first page]

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)  Can you please make the needed changes?