# Is there a LaTeX style that mirrors Practical Typography's suggestions for research paper layout?

Tags: formatting, packages, document-classes

Matthew Butterick of *Practical Typography* says that his preferred format (and, co-incidentally, the one I have to use for my technical writing class final paper) is one where

> 1. Page mar­gins [are] larg­er; line length [is] short­er (about 65 char­ac­ters per line).
> 2. Point size [is] smaller.
> 3. Line spac­ing [is] reduced.
> 4. Better fonts [are used] (Equity and Concourse)
> 5. [There is only] one space be­tween sentences.
> 6. Hyphenation [is] turned on [and]
> 7. [There is] no underlining.

**Sample PDF**
[image: The sample research paper]
**Links**

- [Description ofthe  research paper formatting/layout](http://practicaltypography.com/research-papers.html)
- [Sample PDF of research paper (1 page)](http://practicaltypography.com/samples/research-paper-after.pdf)

Is there some predefined documentclass or style that meets the criteria above? If not, how would I implement such a style myself?

Comment: What exactly is the question? To me it looks like your text just ends somewhere in the middle of nowhere without stating, what information your are searching for. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @BenediktBauer. I'm trying to see (a) if there's a pre-existing style that looks like this PDF I've submitted, and/or (b) how I can create such a style/layout if there's no pre-existing style. I'm not sure which tags I should have appended to this question.

Comment: The points you give are very vague: just sounds like 'not a manuscript, a typeset document'. Can you tell us exactly where you are struggling?

Comment: Take a class of the KOMA-script bundle, e.g. scrartcl. All the items you mention have been incorporated. Read especially the pages about typearea in the manual.

Comment: If it's a research paper you should use the style of the conference or journal. Many journals/conferences have LaTeX class/style files.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, the Q, possibly updated since you read it, is about a class paper, so no journal is involved.

Comment: I don't know what practical about this but looks like a letter than a paper. Less text doesn't necessarily mean huge margins.

Comment: For 65 characters per line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59657/7883 and change `\GetTextWidth{\bringhurstwdt}{66}` to `\GetTextWidth{\bringhurstwdt}{65}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a starter, built on MacTeX 2013 with the [Charter](http://practicaltypography.com/charter.html) font installed:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=2in,rmargin=2in]{geometry} % wider margins
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing % 130% spacing between lines:
% http://texblog.org/2011/09/30/quick-note-on-line-spacing/

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\setmainfont{Charter}
\setlength\parindent{22pt} % indentation

\title{Butterick Example}
\author{Mike Renfro}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newlength{\alphabetlength}
\settowidth{\alphabetlength}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\section{Introduction}

One Charter alphabet at 11~point measures \the\alphabetlength, and doing
some calculations, it looks like using left and right margins of about 2~inches
is going to work. Now, let's set a paragraph using some dummy text from the
\verb|lipsum| package.

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use pdfLaTeX, you can just load `\usepackage{XCharter}` package.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
% put your font commands here for the fonts
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing\raggedright
... your document here
\end{document}
```

^^ this pretty much does the job. You might add `\usepackage[small]{titlesec}` if "small fonts" ought to apply to titles as well. Btw, in your example, there's a hyphenated word `buff-er` leaving only 2 letters on the next line, which is not quite good. As well, mixture of hyphenation and raggedright layout is quite strange. So I'm not sure if you really want something to look like the example text