# 66 characters per line using Lawtex

Tags: spacing, fontsize, linewidth

I'm writing a legal brief and was hoping to use latex with [lawtex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/) . Lawtex works rather well except I'm writing a Letter Brief and need the characters in a line including spaces to be no wider than 66 characters and no bigger than 14pt. I've tried ;

- \fontsize{size}{skip},
- \usepackage{anyfontsize}
- scrartcl
- and found the suggestion in post
  [Nicely force 66 characters per line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line).

I was hoping to get the last option
[Nicely force 66 characters per line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line)
working but maybe I'm missing something because I can't get it to work. Nothing changes when I add it. In MS Word, or Libre Office Writer(preferred) using 14pt with .3 expanded spacing works but doesn't handle the citing(at least I don't know how to make citing work in the word processors).

So my question is since I could not get the macro (Nicely force 66 characters per line) to work with the lawtex package. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better work around? Any help would be appreciated. Here's an example. but I need it to not exceed 66 characters per line with a 1 in margin and with 14pt times new roman font.

[image: sample]

Code

````
\providecommand{\documentclassflag}{}
\documentclass[12pt\documentclassflag]{lawbrief} 
%\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{setspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcommand*\GetTextWidth[3][\normalfont\normalsize]{{#1%
        \settowidth{#2}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}%
        \setlength{#2}{0.03193#2}%
        \addtolength{#2}{0.4961pt}%
        \setlength{#2}{#3#2}%
        \global#2=#2}}

\newlength\bringhurstwdt
\GetTextWidth{\bringhurstwdt}{66}
\geometry{textwidth=\bringhurstwdt}


\begin{document}

    \section*{PRELIMINARY STATEMENT}
    \doublespacing
 On July 11, 2016, approximately between 9 a.m. and 1 p.m.,
 plaintiff Goldi Locks participated in a yoga class at Forest
 Park Plaza in Pretend Ville, New Jersey. (Pa2; Pa14). At the end
 of class, plaintiff was unable to find a ride home. (Pa2; Pa14).
 She decided to walk home, although it was hot and humid that
 day, about 90 degrees Fahrenheit. (Pa2; Pa14).
 At about 1:45 p.m., plaintiff was mid-way home and was
 walking on Warm Welcome Avenue in Fairytale, Mercer County, New
 Jersey. (Pa3). Plaintiff felt fatigued and hungry and decided to
 look for a place to stop and get rest and food before continuing
 her walk home. (Pa3; Pa13). At about 1:55 p.m., plaintiff came
 across a building with an open door and mat that said "WELCOME
 FRIENDS." (Pa3; Pa13). There were no signs on the property
 indicating the building was private or warning people to keep
 off of the property. (Pa3; Pa13; Pa23).
 Plaintiff entered the building, hoping to get food and
 rest. (Pa3; Pa13). There were no people in the building, but
 plaintiff found three different sized bowls of porridge on a
 counter. (Pa3; Pa13). Since plaintiff was hungry, she decided to
 try a spoonful of porridge from the largest bowl first, but it
 was too hot and she burned her tongue. (Pa3; Pa13). Plaintiff
 then tried the porridge in the mid-sized bowl and it was too
 cold. (Pa3; Pa13). Plaintiff finally tried the porridge in the
 smallest bowl and exclaimed, "Yummy! This one is just
 right!" (Pa3; Pa13).

    
\end{document} ```
````

Comment: "Here's an example. but I need it to not exceed 66 characters per line with a 1 in margin and with 14pt times new roman font." your problem seems to have to many constraints. If you specify letter paper and 1in margiins and 14pt, the number of characters is fixed. If that is not 66, to change it do you want to change the margins or change the font size?

Comment: Do you have to use times? TNR is narrow. If you choose a fatter font it may work better.

Comment: Do you really want this to be justified? If you're having a limit of 66 characters per line, left-aligned would probably make more sense.

Comment: "Characters per line" implies a monospace font (see Rule 32, Federal Rules of Appellate Procedure, https://www.ca7.uscourts.gov/Rules/type.pdf and https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frap/rule_32. The FRAP recognize typography and allow leeway (e.g., 72 characters). The actual specification you are adhering to would be most helpful to know.

Comment: Also, avoid using a font that has been designed for narrow newspaper columns in a wide-column brief-length or book-length document. See the pdf link.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you used expanded spacing on a Word Processor.
You *can* do something similar with `microtype`, which you've loaded, but... with your specified 1 inch margin, the output isn't pretty.

To get close to 66 characters per line, I need to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[letterspace=250]{microtype}

\begin{document}


\lsstyle
On July 11, 2016, approximately between 9 a.m. and 1 p.m., 
 plaintiff Goldi Locks participated in a yoga class at Forest 
 Park Plaza in Pretend Ville, New Jersey. (Pa2; Pa14). At the end 
 of class, plaintiff was unable to find a ride home. (Pa2; Pa14). 
 She decided to walk home, although it was hot and humid that
 day, about 90 degrees Fahrenheit. (Pa2; Pa14).
 At about 1:45 p.m., plaintiff was mid-way home and was
 walking on Warm Welcome Avenue in Fairytale, Mercer County, New
 Jersey. (Pa3). Plaintiff felt fatigued and hungry and decided to
 look for a place to stop and get rest and food before continuing
 her walk home. (Pa3; Pa13). At about 1:55 p.m., plaintiff came
 across a building with an open door and mat that said "WELCOME
 FRIENDS." (Pa3; Pa13). There were no signs on the property
 indicating the building was private or warning people to keep
 off of the property. (Pa3; Pa13; Pa23).
 Plaintiff entered the building, hoping to get food and
 rest. (Pa3; Pa13). There were no people in the building, but
 plaintiff found three different sized bowls of porridge on a
 counter. (Pa3; Pa13). Since plaintiff was hungry, she decided to
 try a spoonful of porridge from the largest bowl first, but it
 was too hot and she burned her tongue. (Pa3; Pa13). Plaintiff
 then tried the porridge in the mid-sized bowl and it was too
 cold. (Pa3; Pa13). Plaintiff finally tried the porridge in the
 smallest bowl and exclaimed, "Yummy! This one is just
 right!" (Pa3; Pa13).
\end{document}
```

which outputs something that I wouldn't exactly call legible.

[image]

---

As remarked in the comments, I overlooked the possibility of using 14pt fonts. So here's a version with 14pt (using the [extsizes](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes?lang=en) package). The letterspacing can be less aggressive, but the added spacing still makes the text hard to read in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[letterspace=180]{microtype}

\begin{document}...
```

[image]

---

If you are open to using a font different from `times`, the output can be a lot more pleasant. For example, the following uses the Libre Baskerville font (which is a lot wider than times) and a much less aggressive letter spacing. Combined with double spacing it actually looks normal.

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage[letterspace=40]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\lsstyle
\noindent On July 11, 2016, approximately between 9 a.m. and 1 p.m., 
 plaintiff Goldi L...
```

[image]

Comment: +1 although OP said it was OK to use 14bp fonts which would allow you to use less aggressive letter spacing

Comment: Yes, you are right, let me include a 14pt example too. It is marginally better.

Comment: That's not bad Willie Wong . I think the 14pt font is good however it should only be for the text in  the section but not the section title (\section{Text} ). My example is minimal as there are other sections that I will be adding later. How can I change that? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: How the fonts used for section titles are configured depends a lot on the documentclass used and packages loaded. You may want to look into the documentation for lawtex to see if there's something built in; if not, titlesec is a commonly used package for these kinds of things.

Comment: Thanks! I will see what I come up with and post if/as I find solutions